# PHP - Navigation using a switch statement

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I feel like the following script file should work for navigation on my site, but when I click around on the links nothing loads up and nothing loads by default. How do I fix it?

```
<html>
    <head><title>Your Title</title></head>
    <body>
        Navigation:

        <a href="?id=default">News</a>
        <a href="?id=what1">Whatever1</a>

        <br /><br />

        <?php
            $id = $_GET;
            switch($id)
            {
                default:
                    include('home.html');
                break;

                case "what1":include('whatever1');
                break;

                case "what2":include('whatever2');
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you `$_GET`ing? Also `$_GET` returns an associative array, and the `switch` statement takes a variable. You need to specify what it is you get by giving it an id like `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go in to the $_GET variable and pull out the exact field you want:
$_GET['id']

Answer (score 0):

You don't store the actual `GET` variable in $id,

```
$id = $_GET;
```

should be

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```